# Next.js getServerSideProps always undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next.js and am trying to figure out how to use `getServerSideProps`. From my understanding I can essentially write server side code and it will execute when i load the page and the page will have the data passed in.  What I am finding is that the `data` on the page is always `undefined`.  I cant seem to figure out where I am going wrong.  The code to get the records from my DB is executing and retrieving the records fine.

Can someone please give me some tips? Here is my code below...

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
   
    const datastore = new Datastore();

    const query = datastore.createQuery('kind1')
        .limit(100);
    const [entities] = await datastore.runQuery(query);
    const e = entities.map(e => {
        console.log(e)
        return {
            "id": e[datastore.KEY].id,
            "name": e.name
        }
    });
    console.log(e)
    const obj = {
        props: {
            results:[1,2,3],
        },
    }
    console.log(obj.props.requests)
    return obj
}

export default function AdminDashboard( { data } ) {
    console.log(data)
return (
        <>
            
            .....
            
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your object doesnt have the `data` property, instead use `results`.
You are trying to destruct the returning `props` from your `getServerSideProps` and `data` doesnt exists there.

Comment: Great, this fixed it.  Was not aware they had to share the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your getServerSideProps, you are setting results in props.

```
const obj = {
        props: {                      
            results:[1,2,3],    //Here
        },
    }
```

So, in your AdminDashBoard, your props will contain results instead of data which you are trying to destructure. So, destructure results instead

```
export default function AdminDashboard( { results } ) {
console.log(results)
return <></>
}
```

Here is [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering)

Comment: Thanks, was not aware they needed to share the same name.